# How to add an index column in a dataframe which is read from a csv?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read from a csv file and build a dataframe :

```
nodes_df = pd.read_csv('endpoints_nodes.csv')
```

nodes_df dataframe looks like this :

```
id  ColA   ColB
101  ABC   lst1
102  BCD   lst2
```

i need to add an index column to this:

```
   id  ColA  ColB
0  101 ABC    lst1
1  102 BCD    lst2
```

Comment: Use `index_col=None` in `read_csv`

Comment: @jezrael : index_col=None doesnt work..When i do index_col=False, it says list index out of range. My csv doesnt have an index column, i need to add one

Comment: Problem is not easy testing, is possible share data if not confidental?

Comment: endpoint,function-col,,,,,
products,[{'function':'detach','column':'Options'},{'function':'pop','column':'price'},{'function':'truncdict_image','column':'image'}]
products,[{'function':'detach','column':'images'}],,,,

Comment: this is the csv, i just need to add an index column so that i can iterate through the dataframe.

Comment: I think `csv` file